# tableView deleting more than one cell with deleteRowsAtIndexPaths method

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view with two custom cells, one of those cells has custom button (subclassed uibutton to hold the indexpath). I created a custom delegate for the cell with the custom button, here is the code of the delegate method:

```
func indexOfClassDeletedInTableView(path:NSIndexPath, table:UITableView) {
    let classToDelete = self.classesScheduled[path.row]
    ManagedObjectsController.sharedInstance.deleteScheduledClass(classToDelete) { (succedeed) in
        if (succedeed == true) {
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(self.itemSuccesFullyDeletedFromPersonalView, object: nil)
            self.classesScheduled.removeAtIndex(path.row)
            table.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([path], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        } else {
            print("failed to delete class from personal schedule")
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is that the first time the method gets called, the table deletes the cell at the indexpath given and the one below it. After the first call it works fine and suddenly the extra cell deleted reappears. The custom delegate method (indexOfClassDeletedInTableView) is in my datasource. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using an `NSFetchedResultsController`?

Comment: @Paulw11 what do you mean? I'm not, i do a fetch request in my view controller to populate the table but how would that affect the tableview/cell behavior when deleteing a cell?

Comment: If you are using an `NSFetchedResultsController` then it will fire delegate callbacks when you delete an item which when combined with your code could result in multiple deletions from the `classesScheduled` array, that is why I ask how you are querying core data

Comment: No, im not using it (i wasnt even aware of it lol but siinds very useful) and it seems that it doesnt delete the object below to the indexpath  passed because it reappears when i tap the delete cell button again. Almost like there is not enough cells?

Comment: At least part of your problem is that storing index paths in cells is fragile; when you delete a row, any index paths stored in cells after that row are now incorrect; they all need to be reduced by one. If you do want to store something, it is better to store the NSManagedObject itself and then search the array to find the appropriate index.  Probably an even better approach is to use the standard `swipe to delete` function that is supported by UITableView as this is a consistent user experience.  You should also look at NSFetchedResultsController.